# Arduino replace old relays

Tags: arduino

I have some old relays that controlls an hydraulic motor.

I want to control it with my Arduino. Is this possible?
The relays used are:

**DIL 00 52 from klockner moeller.**

[image]

this is the situation:
[image]

I have experience with the arduino but not that much about electrical schemas?
Is there someone that can help me?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for the [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Of course it's possible. You may want to consider using opto-isolators.

Answer (score 1):

Is this equipment functional now?

The part you have pictured looks like it is for an engine lathe, not a pump.

The amount of rust in the box and corrosion on the overloads and relay would make me think that it has run either outdoors, or in a corrosive environment for quite a while with the door open. Why would you run it with the door open?

Because you have to continually reset the overload and or adjust the timer, or tap on the contacts to get them to engage. Either way, this thing is a mess.

The relays you have shown will interface easily with your arduino, but I WOULD NOT replace what's in the cabinet with these.

The set up in this cabinet is for three phase power. The one on top is the main contactor, and the two side by side units are for reversing the motor. Something you don't want to do with a pump.

My advice to you is to find an electrician before going any further with the power end of this project.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible but probably that relay won't fit the load.

You have to be sure to use relay that can sustain at least the same load and spike current (and voltage), or you many bad thing may happen, like melting togheder the relay contact or burn your house down.

i can't see the code on the relay in the second picture, neiter you had given the load information, so i can't help you more.